# Java JButtons doesnt appear on the JFrame

Tags: java, swing

Here's the significant fragment of JFrame HidingOperationView:

```
 hideBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
               @Override
               public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0){

                   currentPixelInImageToHide.setVisible(true);
                   pixelOfToHideTable.setVisible(true);

                   nextStep.setVisible(true);
                   doAll.setVisible(true);                      

                   SteganographyOperationsUtil.hidingOperation(
                               getSelectedFirstImageModel(), copyOfToHide, posterisation);  

               }                    
            });    
            nextStep.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
               @Override
               public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0){                      
                   SteganographyOperationsUtil.key=1;
            }                    
            }); 
            doAll.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
               @Override
               public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0){
                   SteganographyOperationsUtil.key2=1;
            }                    
            });
```

key and key2 are my controlers in the class SteganographyOperationsUtil, when to wait within the loop:

int key = 1
int key2 = 0

Key controled by the button 'next step', so the loop would go only once forward, show the results in the JTables and wait for another click.
Key2 controled by the button 'doAll', which allows the loop run till the end without stopping.

in the hiding operation:

```
    for (int x = 0; x < hiding.getWidth(); ++x) {
        for (int y = 0; y < hiding.getHeight(); ++y) {

            if(temp < header.length()){
               ...
            }else{
                while (key!=1){
                    sleep(100);
                }
                key=key2;
                ...

                if (key2 == 0){

                    throwToTable(HidingOperationView.pixelOfToHideTable, 
                            colorOfToHideBinary);
                }
            }
       }    
      }
```

The problem is that the buttons that control the loop doesn't appear at all,
they only do, when i comment the line:
    SteganographyOperationsUtil.hidingOperation(                                  getSelectedFirstImageModel(), copyOfToHide, posterisation);

Maybe it's not best way to control the loop, but i have no clue, how to do it otherwise.

Comment: It's difficult to be sure, but you could be blocking the Event Dispatching Thread, preventing it from update the UI

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Comment: @MadProgrammer It's seems to be indeed the problem with blocking EDT. As I just read, it could be solved with the SwingWorker. But to do it within the loop seems damn tricky to me... especially because each time when(key==0) I'm updating data on the JFrame. And in the loop some calculations are being proceed before and after this condition.

Comment: Start be separating your UI elements from you calculation elements.  Get the blocking/long running elements out of EDT, where possible group the units of work together